# Android Asyntask, second parameter is sending information before of first

Tags: android, soap, android-asynctask

I need to get the information of the Async methods using SOAP request, from "layer_1" before receiving the information from "layer_2", but sometimes it happens the other way round, is there any way to make "layer_2" wait for the end of "layer_1"?

Its my AsyncTask:

```
  protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String ope = params[0];
        switch (ope)
        {
            case "layer_1":
                if(Util.isNetworkAvailable(mContext.getApplicationContext()))
                {
                    getWebservice = WebService.getLayer(COD_MATRICULA);
                    changeAsync = true;
                }
                break;
            case "layer_2":
                if (Util.isNetworkAvailable(mContext.getApplicationContext())) {
                    if(canMade)
                        message = addUserWeb(User);
                    changeAsync = true;
                    callMessage = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = null;
                    changeAsync = false;
                }
                break;
        }
        publishProgress();
        return null;
    }
```

and in my progressupdate:

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        if (changeAsync)
            verifyUser();

        if(callMessage)
        {
            .......
            callMessage = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used two asyncTask in your project like below

```
//layer_1 
private class AsyncTaskRunner1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       if(Util.isNetworkAvailable(mContext.getApplicationContext()))
            {
                getWebservice = WebService.getLayer(COD_MATRICULA);
                changeAsync = true;
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        AsyncTaskRunner2 myTask = new AsyncTaskRunner2();
        myTask.execute();
    }
}

//layer_2 
private class AsyncTaskRunner2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       if (Util.isNetworkAvailable(mContext.getApplicationContext())) {
                if(canMade)
                    message = addUserWeb(User);
                changeAsync = true;
                callMessage = true;
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but is it feasible?